# How do I set the root URL in Ember

Tags: javascript, url, ember.js, router, radix

My Ember app lives in `example.com/path/to/ember_app`.

My problem is that Ember seems to be rooting everything based on the site root, not the root of the application, so when I would expect ember to root to:

```
example.com/path/to/ember_app/**news_items**
```

I'm getting a `500 (Internal Server Error)` (GET) on `example.com/news_items`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. You want people that land in your domain to be redirected to the view that runs the app? If that's the case, you should have an actual link (`<a>` tag) that sends users to the correct path or you force the redirect via code (response redirect or similar).

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I'm not exactly sure if the problem is with my understanding or my execution. If the ember app is located in `example.com/some/path/to/app` will all its roots be based from `example.com/some/path/to/app` or will it try and use the site root as the base for its paths?

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand. Is this the location where your app sits on the host application or is it the address of your API? Ember will use the App's current location as root, and it will also fire requests to that root/resource_name. If `example.com/path/to/ember_app` is the "physical location" your app is in the server, your requests should be going to the same place. You can change that in the adapter tho. If you could explain a little more of your app structure I think it would be easier to understand what is going on.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Thanks for hanging in there. I have resolved the problem now. It was actually somewhere completely different, but my lack of understanding lead me to look in the wrong place. Thanks for clarifying that Ember uses routes/paths relative to the location of the app. I'm just finding the amount of magic in Ember hard to wrap my head around. At least in Rails I have a verbose log to track what's going on. In Ember, it seems that if something is missing, the framework silently creates it and leaves you guessing without an error.

Comment: Yeah. You're [not the only one](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ideas-for-improving-the-getting-started-experience/666/15) who noted that. There are some discussions going on about how to make it easier to understand for developers who are starting with Ember, this might be one of the things that will be improved in the future.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I fully appreciate that there are some things that take a while to understand in any framework. I use Rails a lot and lord knows that has magic in plenty, but at least I get my wrist slapped when something is not where it should be. I've posted another question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579222/verbose-logging-in-ember . Please take a look if you have time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyApp.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {        
    this.transitionTo('example.path');
  }
});
```

this should help you, this basically redirects the index route of your app  to the example.path route.