# Verbose Logging in Ember

Tags: javascript, debugging, logging, console, ember.js

I'm trying to wrap my head around Ember at the moment, but all the magic is making this difficult.

I've set `LOG_TRANSITIONS: true` and `Ember.LOG_BINDINGS = true;` which gives me some minimal logging to the console, but I really need more than that.

I'm particularly struggling with seeing what's going on when Ember is automagically creating Controllers, Views and Templates.

Is there a way to log this aspect of the framework - to see where Ember is looking for Templates/Views/Controllers and when it is creating one on its own volition.

For example, I have the following routes set up:

```
App.Router.map(function() {

  this.route("example_items", {path: "/"});

});
```

with:

```
App.ExampleItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.ExampleItem.find();
  }

});
```

Ember renders my ApplicationController and its `application.handlebars` template:

```
<header class="page-header">
  <h1>Application Template</h1>
</header>
{{outlet}}
```

But fails to render my `example_items.handlebars` template. I get no exception or warning, and if I check the DOM, I can see ember has created a generic view in its place.

The bindings logging shows me that Ember has transitioned to `example_items`, but it seems it hasn't used either my ExampleItemsController, ExampleItemsView or template.

How can I debug a situation like this if I receive no errors or messages?

Edit:

App.ExampleItems View:

```
App.ExampleItemsView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  templateName: 'example_items'
});
```

And App.ExampleItemsController:

```
App.ExampleItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});
```

Comment: What do you mean with example_items.template ?

Are you using precompiled views or <script> tags?

Comment: There is no special logging functionality in the route for this behaviour. Your implementation of `renderTemplate` is redundant but that shouldn't have any effect... a few things: (1) in your view and controller definitions are you `extend`ing them? (2) Are they defined on the App namespace? (3) Just in case it somehow is actually using your view, is the templateName set on it (if it isn't, it won't be used automatically and the view will appear blank)

Comment: @Neikos Sorry. That was a mistype. I have amended it to the correct: `example_items.template`. Using the Rails gem, so Template compilation is automatic (the `application.handlebars` template works fine).

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey Using `renderTemplate` was just desperation. (1/2) Yes - see edit to question. (3) Do you mean on the `ExampleItemsController`? How would I get a reference to it if not from its View or Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm particularly struggling with seeing what's going on when Ember is automagically creating Controllers, Views and Templates.
>
> Is there a way to log this aspect of the framework - to see where Ember is looking for Templates/Views/Controllers and when it is creating one on its own volition.

Yes. With the latest ember you can now `LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION` to see console.log output whenever ember generates something for you.

Another new setting that might be helpful is `LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS`

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem: `CollectionView` won't use your template. It takes an array as its `content` property (usually set up as a binding to the controller) and creates childViews manually. Without a `content` set it'll appear as a blank view.

If you add `classNames: ['my-view']` to your view definition, you should see that the view it's instantiating and inserting is actually your view class, just empty. Add `contentBinding: 'controller'` and it should render itemViews for each item in the array, as well.

Comment: Thanks. You were correct. In this example, I misunderstood the purpose of ArrayView, but I'm stiff baffled by how difficult it is to see what Ember is doing.

Comment: Agreed. This is a prime candidate for optional logging. A github issue asking for improvements in this would not be remiss.